# the login field is not visible after implementing it

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement the login field using django's authenticationForm.

the problem im having is that,because im trying to display two different forms inside one page (post_list) it seem to cause many errors.

one is for login field, and one is for the posting articles.

i also seem to have problem with duplicate forms as the two forms use the samename for the form which i do not know how to change.

also, there an error occurring when i try to post something using the post form.

to blatantly put, how do i make the login field visible?

i refer you to the working site : http://mtode.com( this is just a representation site, and do not contain login field part)

this is my views py which contains the definitions

```
    from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect


from .forms import PostForm, AuthenticationForm
from .models import Post


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def post_detail(request, id=None):
    #instance = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):



    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post-list/')

        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request)

            return TemplateResponse(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})



    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            print (form.cleaned_data.get("title"))
            instance.save()
            # message success
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get())
        #else:
            #messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
    queryset = Post.objects.all()#.order_by("-timestamp")
    context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "title": "List",
            "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>List</h1>")

def post_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Saved")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)


def post_delete(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:list")
```

and this is the forms.py that contains the forms

```
    from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
        "title",
        "content"
        ]

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('invalid_login')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

and this is the post_list.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Username: {{ form.username }} {{ form.username.errors }}<br>
    Password: {{ form.password }} {{ form.password.errors }}<br>
    {{ form.errors }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>


<div class='two columns right mgr'>
  <h1>Form</h1>
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input class="button-primary" type='submit' value='Create Post' />
</form>
</div>

<div class='four columns left'>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

{% for obj in object_list %}



<div class="row">
  <div>
    <a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <!--<img src="..." alt="...">!-->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{ obj.title }}<small> {{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small></h3>
        <p>{{ obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
      <!--  <p><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a> </p>-->
      </div>


    </div></a>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>

{% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When your page is initially displayed, `request.method` is `GET`.  Therefore the post_list view is creating a `PostForm` instance and passing that into your template as the `form` element.

`PostForm` does not have `username` or `password` attributes, so those items are treated as empty strings and do not render at all.

If you want a template to render two forms, you need to pass them as separate names.  You can't call them both "form".

Comment: Yes. i understand that part well. but in this case, specifically what do you suggest i do? keep in mind, i am not good at reading the python language thus cannot think of any way to insert a few lines for the GET case. I've tried changing the request.method =="GET" see if that works out as well, but apparently it spits errors that i do not understand. obviously what i can do is very limited. could you care to explain to me what i need to do in order to make the login form appear and the post form as well ? I tried to change the name by form2 = AuthenticationForm, but not sure im doing it right

Comment: Since `post_list.html` contains two forms, you should always pass two form objects whenever you render that template.  Perhaps call them `authform` and `postform` in the `context` dictionary, and also edit the template to use the separate names.

Comment: thanks for the instruction. they were helpful.  but despite the effort to put a few lines for GET request method,  now i am stuck with another error saying 'local variable 'form' referenced before assignment' . could you explain how i can possibly get away from this situation? here is my dpaste for the views.py https://dpaste.de/mvsZ#L

Comment: The problem is in your `context` dictionary, on the line `"form2": form,`.  At this point in your code, there is no object named `form`.  (`form` is created earlier in the function if request.method is "POST", however if "request.method" is not "POST", `form` does not exist.)